# Windows Server 2008 R2 - Giving local administrator full rights to all folders

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, permissions

Is there a quick way to give the local administrator full rights to all folders on the C drive?  I am having really hard time with that, I try to give it full rights to some folders (user profiles) but I can't even modify the NTFS permissions in some cases, I get "permission denied"

Is there some soft of tutorial or script that will just give the administrator full rights on all folders in the C driver?

Many thanks for your help!
Toast

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/53325/resetting-ntfs-permissions-disk-wide

Comment: not the same, my setup is a fresh install. Btw, UAC is disabled

Comment: You tried the takeown & icacls commands in Evan's post to reset permissions on a test folder that you wanted access to?  What was the exact output?

Comment: You've described at least two really poor practices here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first set the owner to "Administrators" and then in a second step you can change the permissions. If you want to automate that or set permissions from the command line SetACL might be the tool of choice. Examples follow.

[Setting the owner of an entire tree to administrators and enabling inheritance on the child objects](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/examples/managing-file-system-permissions-with-setacl-exe/#example-1-12-setting-the-owner):

```
SetACL.exe -on "C:\" -ot file -actn setprot -op "dacl:np;sacl:nc" 
           -rec cont_obj -actn setowner -ownr "n:S-1-5-32-544;s:y"
```

[Adding full permissions for administrators:](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/examples/managing-file-system-permissions-with-setacl-exe/#example-1-1-setting-permissions)

```
SetACL.exe -on "C:\" -ot file -actn ace -ace "n:S-1-5-32-544;s:y;p:full"
```