# Windows Server 2008 r2 security permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions, security-groups

I hope I've selected the correct StackExchange for this question. I have searched google and StackExchange but haven't been able to find an answer to my question with the search queries used.

I setup a home server as a little project to learn the basics of the Windows Server environment in October 2015. It has worked well and served the purposes I set it up for since.

However, I made a mistake a couple of weeks ago....

Imagine for a second that someone could be stupid enough (or just had a complete lapse in concentration!) to remove 'Full control' for the Administrators on the primary data HDD.

[Data drive permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p22jL.png)

Is there any way to revert this permission change short of reinstalling the OS?

Thanks

Comment: See the accepted answer on this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/53325/resetting-ntfs-permissions-disk-wide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can boot the system with a live Windows CD/DVD/USB and use "TAKEOWN" and "ICACLS":

`TAKEOWN /f "X:\" /r /d y
ICACLS "X:\" /reset /T`

If you do not have a live Windows, extract the HDD's and connect them another windows machine and reset them from there.

Comment: Thank you joeqwerty and Oniceag George. I have done as suggested which has given permission to my user. Hasn't completely resolved the problem but answers the question I raised perfectly :)